# Axios url won't preserve encoded period

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am calling `axios.post` with the url:

```
/constituents/941802/activities/rid/941802/rtype/Constituent/to/2021-10-01/type/Vol%2E%20Time?format=json
```

But it sends

```
/constituents/941802/activities/rid/941802/rtype/Constituent/to/2021-10-01/type/Vol.%20Time?format=json
```

How do I prevent this?

Using Axios 0.21.1

I have seen the suggestion of adding a trailing `'/'` at the end of the path, but that does not prevent the conversion and the server still finds the format to be illegal.

Sample:

```
  post(url) {
    return axios.post(
      url, 
      {},
      {responseType: 'json', headers: { 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip' }}
    )
  }
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: It's pretty straight forward. Nothing to show, but added none the less.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with Chrome, not Axios. It works fine in Firefox and Safari.